# Correct way to treat if else with no else to do

Tags: python, if-statement

Suppose I have an `if` clause to do something if `condition == True` and nothing if it's `False`. I can think of three ways to put it: omitting the `else` statement like this:

```
beginning of code
if condition == True:
     do something
rest of the code
```

Explicitly telling python to do nothing:

```
beginning of code
if condition == True:
     do something
else:
     pass
rest of the code
```

And another, probably-not-so-good-practice version that repeats the rest of the code:

```
if condition == True:
     do something
     rest of the code
else:
     rest of the code
```

The first one is surely shorter, but is one of them more efficient than the other? Are there other differences between these codes other than clearness?

Comment: This is opinion-based. Many opinions will be fantastically wrong, but that's of course just my opinion.

Comment: `if`` *already* tests for truth, using `== True` is entirely redundant and can lead to operator chaining errors. Don't use it.

Comment: Your examples aren't all logically equivalent; the first runs either `do something` **or** `rest of the code`, the others always runs `rest of the code`.

Comment: True! Hadn't realized that. I'll edit the question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your second example more clearly expresses what you want, assuming you do want the `rest of code` to be executed regardless.